# semanage command not changing file context

Tags: linux, centos-6, selinux

I am trying to change selinux context for upload directory to enable anonymous upload.

This is the Directory path /var/ftp/upload

This is the default context

```
[root@server ftp]# ls -Z upload
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 upload
```

I tried this command to change the type of the directory

```
[root@server ftp]# semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_rw_t upload
```

```
[root@server ftp]# restorecon -v upload
```

Its not changing, what is the mistake here ?

```
[root@server ftp]# ls -Z pub
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 upload
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default context

```
[root@server ftp]# ll -Zd upload/
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 upload/
```

I tried this command to change the context

```
[root@server ftp]# semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_rw_t upload/
[root@server ftp]# ll -Zd upload/
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 upload/
```

```
[root@server ftp]# restorecon -R -v upload
[root@server ftp]# ll -Zd upload/
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 upload/
```

It's not working, but this command will write the context in `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local` file

see here

```
# This file is auto-generated by libsemanage
# Do not edit directly.

upload/    system_u:object_r:public_content_rw_t:s0
```

Now I tried this command (**Working Command**)

```
[root@server ftp]# semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_rw_t "/var/ftp/upload(/.*)?"
```

```
[root@server ftp]# restorecon -R -v upload
restorecon reset /var/ftp/upload context unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0->unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_rw_t:s0
```

```
Now context is changed.
[root@server ftp]# ll -Zd upload/
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_rw_t:s0 upload/
```

But I really don't no why it's working, see the difference in command.

I got the answer in the man page of `man ftpd_selinux`

```
semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_rw_t "/var/ftpd/incoming(/.*)?"
```

Answer (score 6):

The difference between semange and chcon is that chcon is "temporal" if the system gets relabel the contexts present in a file / directory will be lost, using semanage makes selinux contexts persistent.

In order to semanage to work, you must provide the full path to the file or directory, that is why 
`semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_rw_t upload/` does not work but `semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_rw_t "/var/ftp/upload(/.*)?` does; restorecon does not require full path.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files-persistent_changes_semanage_fcontext):

> The `file_contexts.local` file stores contexts to **newly created files and directories not found in `file_contexts`**.

That's why you find the log message in `file_contexts.local`.

> When changing the SELinux context with `semanage fcontext -a`, use the **full path** to the file or directory to avoid files being mislabeled after a file system relabel, or after the `restorecon` command is run.

This is the hint to use the full path for right relabeling.

Comment: Which means you need to specify the absolute path instead of the relative path for semanage command.

Answer (score -1):

Try

> chcon -t public_content_rw_t /var/ftp/upload

It will work.

Comment: First of all it is not `chcon -R` , it should be `chcon -t` (for this particular example) and one more thing I think it is not the  permanent method, now type `resorecon -v upload` and check it will change the context to default.